# EF migration generating duplicated FK with different name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm Trying to rename the Default FK, but Code First Migration keep generating a second FK to the same table with a different name, messing up the Table schema.

The FK Model has a PK named Id, I just want to keep the convention required by my client, changing the name for Id(something).

**1) Generated migration:**

[image: Generated Migration]

**2) Mapping:**

[image: Code First Map]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If your `CorpoGestor` entity exposes a property for the foreign key, use `HasForeignKey` instead of `Map`and `MapKey`.

```
HasRequired(x => x.Conselho)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdConselho);
```

Another solution: you can use the `ForeignKey` attribute in the property, instead of mapping the relation in the `CorpoGestorMap` class:

```
public class CorpoGestor
{
    ...

    public int IdConselho { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdConselho")]
    public virtual Conselho Conselho { get; set; }
}
```

A warning: using attributes in the entities is conceptually not so cool as implementing the code in the `EntityTypeConfiguration` mapping classes, because you are polluting your entities with data layer code that should be kept in the EF classes.